# Convert format HH:MM:SS to seconds in a column with AWK

Tags: linux, unix, awk

i have a table

```
RMA###Order###FR2345###00:56:10###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###00:30:20###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###1:00:20:40###TI685
```

i need replace the field DD:HH:MM:SS to seconds

```
RMA###Order###FR2345###3370###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###1820###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###87640###TI685
```

the table is separate by '###' but the field is by ':'

i ussing

```
echo "1:00:20:40" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 86400)+($2 * 3600) + ($3 * 60) + $4 }'
87640
```

to convert

and to separate the table

```
awk  -F, 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="###"}
```

but how separate the field by ':' and convert to seconds in the same script?

Comment: I see you're new to stack overflow. There are many people who have answered your question, so if you find one that is sufficient, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put this into a.awk

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "###"
}
{
    b = split($4,a,":")
    if (b == 4) {
      print $1, $2, $3, (a[1] * 86400)+(a[2] * 3600) + (a[3] * 60) + a[4], $5   
    } else {
      print $1, $2, $3, (a[1] *3600) + (a[2] * 60) + a[3], $5
    }
}
```

And then run

```
awk -f a.awk foo.txt
```

You will get the desired output:

```
RMA###Order###FR2345###3370###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###1820###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###87640###TI685
```

Comment: nice, thanks man, thats work but if i have null fields like this  RMA###Order######00:56:10###AK234 thats work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function:

```
awk '{ split($0,a,":"); print (a[1]*86400)+(a[2]*3600)+(a[3]*60)+a[4] }' <<< '1:00:20:40'
87640
```

So you don't mess with `FS`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. you're right, but point was to show he can use split function. I will remove the wrong part to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution,

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="###";
  split("1 60 3600 86400", vconv, " ");
}
{
  n=split($4,vtime,":")
  seconds = 0;
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    seconds += vconv[i] * vtime[n-i+1];
  }
  $4 = seconds;
  print;
}' input
```

you get:

```
RMA###Order###FR2345###3370###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###1820###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###87640###TI685
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="###"} 
            {n=split($4,t,":");
             s=0;
             if(n==4)s=24*t[1]; 
             s=((s+t[n-2])*60+t[n-1])*60+t[n]; $4=s}1' file 

RMA###Order###FR2345###3370###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###1820###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###87640###TI685
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@test /tmp]$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="###"}{s=split($4,t,":");$4=t[s]+t[s-1]*60+t[s-2]*3600+t[s-3]*86400}1' file.txt

RMA###Order###FR2345###3370###AK234
FWA###working###FR1345###1820###DE432
HQP###cat1###FR6798###87640###TI685
```